# ¿Cómo crear un nuevo layout en laravel 8 con tailwind?

Tags: laravel, tailwind

Estoy iniciando con Laravel 8, y por defecto trae dos layouts ubicados en la ruta `views/layouts/` y el directorio contiene dos archivos `app.blade.php` y `guest.blade.php` cuando se hace el llamado a dichos layouts, ejemplo en el dashboard, funciona:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                <x-jet-welcome />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Pero si creo un nuevo layout `index.blade.php` y lo llamo:

```
<x-index-layout>
    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                <x-jet-welcome />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-index-layout>
```

Me da un error: `InvalidArgumentException Unable to locate a class or view for component [index-layout].`

Me imagino que debo hacer algo más, pero no sé qué.

Comment: Tailwind tiene una guía oficial sobre la instalación en Laravel, ¿ya la checaste? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel

Comment: Hola, sí la revisé pero no veo nada al respecto. Con la última versión de laravel todo viene integrado.

Comment: De hecho pienso que está más relacionado con Blade que con Tailwind, no estoy seguro. Porque  se  trata de la etiqueta `<x-index-layout>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justo el otro día generé un layout nuevo para un proyecto de laravel, debes crear un componente mediante artisan: `php artisan make:component IndexLayout` y luego en `App\View\Components\IndexLayout.php` puedes modificar la vista que devuelve.

EDIT:
pon esto en tu Componente:

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('layouts.index');
    }
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo!

Comment: Gracias, si me funciona, pero o sé si es la mejor manera, pues está el directorio `layouts` esperaré a ver si otra persona nos pueda ayudar, igualmente me es util tu información nuevamente gracias.

Comment: También en mi caso, tengo un directorio dentro de `views` llamado `vendor` dentro de este otro llamado `jetstream` y dentro de este último uno llamado `componets` en este caso, debería tenerlo allí, no? la ruta es `resources/views/vendor/jetstream/componets`

Comment: he editado mi respuesta, puedes elegir la vista que devuelve el componente, por si quieres meter la vista en una carpeta diferente ;) espero que ahora te haya quedado claro, un abrazo

Comment: Ya encontré como, es básicamente lo que tu dices, pero se debe renderizar en `app/View/Components`

Comment: pero creando manualmente el archivo para renderizar y evitar que genere otro directorio